# VS Code integrated terminal keeps saying "chdir(2) failed: Permission denied"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm new to coding and recently I had a problem with Visual Studio Code.

So basically I have to reinstall VS Code due to it kinda messing up my desktop.

And then, all of a sudden the integrated terminal won't work any more.

Now whenever I tried to run my code it just flashes this:
`chdir(2) failed: Permission denied` and it exits with code 1.

I tried reinstalling, run it as superuser and it didn't work.

Here's the video: https://streamable.com/ksbsxx

Can somebody help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the vscode from the official site? use "sudo code" for run vscode and test again

Comment: Thanks, the superuser VS Code worked, but how to make the non-root VS Code work again? It used to work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out.

Removing everything related to Visual Studio Code (yes, even hidden caches and stuff) and reinstall VS Code worked for me.

I hope this will work for everyone else as it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo chmod 755 /home/dennis and then log in again